# How to handle errors thrown by couchbase SDK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase, couchbase-nodejs-sdk

I have a NodeJS application which connects to couchbase and uses its sdk("couchbase": "^2.0.8") to connect and execute queries. In some cases the SDK code throws error like this:

```
Bucket.prototype.getMulti = function(keys, callback) {
  if (!Array.isArray(keys) || keys.length === 0) {
    throw new TypeError('First argument needs to be an array of length > 0.');
  }
  if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('Second argument needs to be a callback.');
  }
  .
  .
  .
};
```

and this is how I am calling it:

```
try {
  bucket.getMulti(keys, function(err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    .
    .
    .
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Since the error is not sent in callback so there is no way to check and respond appropriately to the client, it is simply crashing the app. I can do these checks before calling this particular function but there are many other functions like these which are throwing errors, what is the best way to handle them and respond to client instead of crashing the app?

Comment: these seem to be sanity-checking of the arguments passed to the function... do you have control on what you pass in as arguments to couchbase methods, or is it somehow dynamic?

Comment: For this particular case I can sanitize the arguments(which is what I am planning if I don't find better solution) but there are many other methods with lots of different cases when errors can be thrown, I can't handle all those beforehand.

Comment: do you have other examples? as the developer you should be able to directly call the methods with correct parameters... if you can't, then wrapping it in a `try{} catch{}` block will allow you to detect input errors and manage them...

Comment: Like reading a file this sdk doesn't provide both sync & async version of function and if I am using async function then try-catch will not help because it cannot catch anything thrown by such method

Comment: Typically the SDK will throw exceptions for argument errors and will use callbacks for actual data errors. This helps you debug invalid inputs when they happen. Data errors need to be received from the server itself and thus must be passed via callback. You should use both `try{}catch{}` and check for the errors in the callback.